# Modifying dynamic column contents

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to create a new column inside a dynamic column.

My table Templates just has two columns: ID, Structure (blob)

I run this query:

```
UPDATE `Templates` SET `Structure` = COLUMN_ADD(`Structure`, 'general', '') where `Templates`.`ID` = 1
```

Structure Result (Using COLUMN_JSON for display):

```
{"general":""}
```

Then I run this query:

```
UPDATE `Templates` SET `Structure` = COLUMN_ADD(COLUMN_GET(`Structure`, 'general' as CHAR), 'Inner', 'value') WHERE `Templates`.`ID` = 1
```

Structure Result:

```
{"Inner":"value"}
```

The result I want after both queries:

```
{"general": {"Inner":"value"}}
```

How can I get a column added to the dynamic "general" column instead of replacing the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is what happens with your query.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE Templates (ID INT, Structure BLOB);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO Templates VALUES (1, COLUMN_CREATE('general',''));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT COLUMN_JSON(Structure) FROM Templates;
+------------------------+
| COLUMN_JSON(Structure) |
+------------------------+
| {"general":""}         |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

At this point you have in `Structure` one dynamic column with name `general` and empty string as a value.

Then you do this:

```
UPDATE `Templates` 
  SET `Structure` = COLUMN_ADD(
    COLUMN_GET(`Structure`, 'general' as CHAR), 
    'Inner', 
    'value'
  ) ...
```

Your `COLUMN_GET` gets the value of `general` dynamic column, which is an empty string, and uses it as the first argument for `COLUMN_ADD`. It's a useless exercise, because if you want to run `COLUMN_ADD` on an empty string, you can just say so in the query or use `COLUMN_CREATE`; and if you want to actually *add* something to the existing value of the blob, you need to use the name of the blob.

So, `COLUMN_ADD` works on an empty string -- in other words, creates a clean new value for `Structure`, discarding everything it had -- and adds a dynamic column with name `Inner` and value `value`. That's why you are getting this:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT COLUMN_JSON(Structure) FROM Templates;
+------------------------+
| COLUMN_JSON(Structure) |
+------------------------+
| {"Inner":"value"}      |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Apparently, what you want to do instead is to set the value of `general` column to a new dynamic column.

You don't need to fetch `general` column for that, because `COLUMN_ADD(x,y,z)` will replace the value if a column `y` already exists in blob `x`. But you need to construct a new dynamic column for the new value of `general`.

So, what you should do is

```
UPDATE `Templates` 
SET `Structure` = COLUMN_ADD(
  `Structure`, 
  'general', 
  COLUMN_CREATE('Inner','value')
) ...
```

This accounts for a more general case when `Structure` also contains other columns, not only `general`, and you want to preserve them. If it's not the case, and you want to make sure the blob contains *only* `general`, then you can do

```
UPDATE `Templates` 
SET `Structure` = COLUMN_CREATE(
  'general', 
  COLUMN_CREATE('Inner','value')
)
```